Update flag based on if values exist in another table for multiple columns
In Snowflake, I would like to update a flag in the current table if there is values matching in 4 columns in another table. Only one columns has to match to set it to True.
data looks like below in table1



id
col1
col2
col3
col4




1
egg
foo
bar
val


2

foo





table2



score
col1
col2
col3
col4




100
egg
foo
bar
val


200

foo





I would like to add a column exists which basically states if col1 in table 1 matches col1 in table2 or col2 in table1 matches col2 in table2 etc..
update table1 a
set exists_in_tbl2 = case when exists(
                 select 1 from table2
                 where (a.col1=b.col1 or a.col2=b.col2 or a.col3 =b.col3 or a.col4=b.col4)
                 ) then true
             else false end;

Problem is the tables are quite large and this query is taking quite a long time to run. Is there a more efficient way of doing so?

FIRST use a default value for your column "exists_in_tbl2" with false
SECOND simply your query to not scan and update everything, like :
update table1
    set    exists_in_tbl2 = true
    WHERE   exists(select 1
                  from   table2
                  where  table1.col1=b.col1 or table1.col2=b.col2 or table1.col3 =b.col3 or table1.col4=b.col4);

If your RDBMS supports columnar index storage like Microsoft SQL Server, use it on both tables for col1 to col4 to run this query with compressed values and a maximum of parallelism...
Another way for speeding this query with a good optimizer is to split the subquery in multiple simplified queries like :
update table1
set    exists_in_tbl2 = true
WHERE  exists(select 1
              from   table2
              where  table1.col1=b.col1
              UNION  ALL
              select 1
              from   table2
              WHERE  table1.col2=b.col2 
              UNION  ALL
              select 1
              from   table2
              WHERE  table1.col3 =b.col3
              UNION  ALL
              select 1
              from   table2
              WHERE  table1.col4=b.col4);

And create 4 indexes on the 4 columns in each tables.

I should have added this is for snowflake, I am getting an unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated.

Try the modification I do for the queries
